# mod_rewrite rule matched, but chain is not left

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please help me to find a solution for this behavior which is very strange to me.

Here is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule     ^emltr\.gif$                   aaa.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                            index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Note the L flag, so I would say that when "gif" rule is matched the chain is left.
But it is not.

The requested URL is "emltr.gif"

If the "catch-all" rule and conditions are commented, then the "gif" rule is correctly taken. ("aaa.html" does not exists, this is a test to prevent unwanted circular behavior.)

If the "catch-all" rule is uncommented, then IT is taken, rather than the first rule. Why is the second one taken rather than the first? Or else: why isn't the chain left even though the L flag, and then second rule is evaluated?

Thank you

Comment: That is how the L works, it doest stop the rewrite iteration. You can use END instead of L to end the rewriting process immediatly when the rule matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the manual [`L|last`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. *In most contexts*, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.
>
> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in `<Directory>` sections, ... The simplified form of this is that once the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or  section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.
>
> An alternative flag, [END], can be used to terminate not only the current round of rewrite processing but prevent any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context. This does not apply to new requests resulting from external redirects.

In short, when you have rewrite rules in an .htaccess file or inside a `Directory` directive, the request will be processed again, if it was rewritten by this round. Only when there is no more rewrite, it will stop.